# JQuery UI Tabs - I want to remove it from the page after a button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I want the panel that contains these tabs to be hidden completely:

I have this bit of code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Hide Tree" onclick="Button2_Click1"   onclientclick="hideTabs()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function hideTabs() {
        $("#tabs").hide();
    }
</script>

//C#
protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
              TreeView1.Visible = false;
}
```

My Tabs Setup

- Tree
- Search

..blah

What am I doing wrong? The TreeView disappears after the button is hit, but not the JQuery UI tabs. Am I doing something wrong with the jQuery syntax?

The page looks like it is being refreshed, which may be a clue.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML your Javascript is trying to deal with, it's impossible to guess what might be going on. Where is `#tabs`? Give us a clue!

Comment: Try using $('#Button2').click(function(){$('#tabs').hide();});

Comment: Please try to come up with a bit more descriptive title.

Comment: The click event is performing its natural behavior and reloading the page.

Comment: A refreshed page (re: @Jay Blanchard's comment) will result in the tabs being redisplayed.  You will need to trigger hideTabs in another way.

Comment: Thanks Pedro - your solution didn't work.

Comment: Jay - what do I have to do? Do I have to put the tabs into something that doesn't refresh, like an Update Panel? I'm new to Jquery.

Comment: Michael_B, Jay Blanchard - is there a 'standard' container for jquery to put Jquery UI widgets into that doesn't refresh? In Microsoft Ajax Control Toolkit, it is the UpdatePanel.